# Get called_/calling_ae_title

Tags: python, dicom, pynetdicom

I'm implementing SCP and I'm not sure how to get calling_/called_ae_title correctly.
I'd like to get called_/calling_ae_title during connection(client sending DICOM image) on the server side. I don't enforce called_ae_title(ae.require_called_aet = False), but set default AE title in SCP. I'd like to use the called_/calling_ae_title for audit purpose.
So, what I can see from the debug log from pytnetdicom SCP that this information is available in the A-ASSOCIATE-RQ PDU

```
D: Request Parameters:
D: ======================= INCOMING A-ASSOCIATE-RQ PDU ========================
D: Their Implementation Class UID:      1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.6.1
D: Their Implementation Version Name:   OSIRIX_361
D: Application Context Name:    1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1
D: Calling Application Name:    NO_CLIENT       
D: Called Application Name:     PYDS            
D: Their Max PDU Receive Size:  16384
D: Presentation Context:
```

According to this document https://pydicom.github.io/pynetdicom/dev/reference/generated/pynetdicom.pdu.A_ASSOCIATE_RQ.html?highlight=calling_ae_title#pynetdicom.pdu.A_ASSOCIATE_RQ.calling_ae_title

I tried this in server side.

```
from pynetdicom.pdu import (A_ASSOCIATE_RQ, A_ASSOCIATE_AC)
...
...
pdu = A_ASSOCIATE_RQ()
print(type(pdu.calling_ae_title))
print(pdu.calling_ae_title)
```

My outputs are during connection:

```
 <class 'bytes'>
b'Default         '
```

I always got "Default" value instead of real values.

What did I do wrong? Or is it a bug? Both calling_ae_title and called_ae_title produce the same "Default" output when I call it.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're creating a new `A_ASSOCIATE_RQ` instance you're getting its default values (i.e. `b'Default'`) because it hasn't been used in any associations.

If you want the actual *Calling AE Title* used by an association requestor then information about the local and peer's association negotiation proposals is available via the [Association.acceptor](https://pydicom.github.io/pynetdicom/stable/reference/generated/pynetdicom.association.Association.html#pynetdicom.association.Association.acceptor) and [Association.requestor](https://pydicom.github.io/pynetdicom/stable/reference/generated/pynetdicom.association.Association.html#pynetdicom.association.Association.requestor) properties:

```py
from pynetdicom import AE, evt
from pynetdicom.sop_class import VerificationSOPClass

def handle_requests(event):
    primitive = event.assoc.requestor.primitive
    print(type(primitive), primitive.calling_ae_title)

ae = AE()
ae.add_supported_context(VerificationSOPClass)
ae.start_server(('', 11112), evt_handlers=[(evt.EVT_REQUESTED, handle_requests)])
```

Where the `primitive` here is an [A-ASSOCIATE primitive](https://pydicom.github.io/pynetdicom/stable/reference/generated/pynetdicom.pdu_primitives.A_ASSOCIATE.html#pynetdicom.pdu_primitives.A_ASSOCIATE).